# index was out of range. must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection while binding data with label

Tags: c#, arrays, binding

I am new to C#... I am taken live data from a sensor that I want to bind in a label so I tried. I think done all correctly but I got the Index was out of range error. Anyone helps me to solve this error below I update my code

Error: Index was out of range. must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection

My Error is mentioned this place  Registers[i].Value = ReadValues[i];
My code:

```
private List<Bind> _Registers = new List<Bind>();
private ModbusClient modbusClient;
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            modbusClient = new ModbusClient("", 502);
            modbusClient.Connect();
            int[] ReadValues = modbusClient.ReadHoldingRegisters(0, 1);
             Registers[i].Value = ReadValues[i]; //Got Error
            txt40001.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", Registers[0], 
             "Value", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged));
        }
         public List<Bind> Registers
        {
            get
            {
                return _Registers;
            }

            set
            {
                _Registers = value;
            }
        }
```

For Bind.cs

```
public class Bind : INotifyPropertyChanged{
        private int _Value;
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String propertyName = ""){
            if (PropertyChanged != null){
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
        public int Value{
            get{ return _Value;}
            set{
                if (_Value != value){
                    _Value = value;
                    NotifyPropertyChanged("Value");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: the error is clear, it means that there is no node with index of `i` in your array.
I think the problem is in `for` loop condition. please give me more information.
what is length of `ReadValues` array ?! is length always same ?!

Comment: length of an array is 1

Comment: Its add to list

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is that your `Register` list has not any member, but you want set its first member in `for` loop so that you got this error. please put below Code:

```
    private List<Bind> _Registers = new List<Bind>();
private ModbusClient modbusClient;
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    modbusClient = new ModbusClient("10.54.11.252", 502);
    modbusClient.Connect();
    int[] ReadValues = modbusClient.ReadHoldingRegisters(0, 1);
    for(var i = 0; i < ReadValues.length; i++)
    {
      Registers.Add(new Bind()
        {
            Value = ReadValues[i];
        });
    }
    txt40001.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", Registers[0],
     "Value", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged));
}
public List<Bind> Registers
{
    get
    {
        return _Registers;
    }

    set
    {
        _Registers = value;
    }
}
```

And i think your problem will solve.

Comment: I don't know where to add this code Please edit my code

Comment: Updated. Check it!

Comment: It Displays first data only but not update automatically